# Redimensionar um elemento filho de acordo com a largura do elemento pai

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf

Tenho um h:inputTextarea dentro de um p:dialog, desse modo:
[image: Exemplo]

Gostaria que conforme eu redimensionasse a p:dialog a h:inputTextarea redimensionasse também, para que, quando eu redimensionar a dialog não fique tão feio como na imagem, e para que eu não precise redimensionar os dois, apenas um só. Mas não tenho ideia de como implementar, não sei se consigo isso só com CSS ou se vou precisar de JavaScript, jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha com CSS é possível sim... primeiro lembro que mediadas em % de um filho é relacionado a largura e altura do pai.

Então vc ve tem um container pai com 200px de altura e 200px da largura, e o filho tem 50% de largura e 50% de altura, esse filho na verdade vai ter 100px de altura e 100% da altura.

Tendo esse conceito em mente veja que é possível ter um `textarea` em % que acompanha o tamanho do pai

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima. No caso o `textaarea` é filho direto do `body`, que tem 100% de altura e largura da janela.

**Exiba em página toda tb para ver o `textarea` redimensionar**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#texto {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="texto" value="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, consequatur accusamus provident quo nisi quae, vero unde, corporis sint atque fuga porro. Quae eligendi voluptates incidunt neque, accusantium labore inventore.</textarea>
```

Comment: Obrigada, era exatamente o que eu procurava e é bem mais simples do que eu pensei que seria

Comment: @JulianaMarques sim a aplicação é bem tranquila e super crossbrowser, boa sorte com o projeto

Answer (score 2):

Olá, bom...

Você terá sim que utilizar o JavaScript para esse tipo de manipulação, opcionalmente poderá utilizar algum dos seus frameworks, porém eu irei exemplificar com o JavaScript puro(VanillaJS).

Para fazer esse tipo de efeito você precisará ativar o evento de "resize" da sua janela wrapper e quando o evento for disparado você precisará capturar o "clientHeight" e o "clientWidth" da sua janela e em seguida atribuir os valores capturados ao seu TEXTAREA, segue exemplos:

```
    // Selecionando elementos...

    // Janela de fora
    let wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

    // Text Area
    let txtarea = document.querySelector('#chat');

    // Ativando evento...

    wrapper.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
        let wrapperWidth = e.target.clientWidth;
        let wrapperHeight = e.target.clientHeight;

        txtarea.style.width = `${wrapperWidth}px`;
        txtarea.style.height = `${wrapperHeight}px`;
    });

    // Pronto, agora sempre que a janela for redimensionada o textarea irá receber as dimensões atualizadas!
```

Comment: Eu precisaria chamar uma função com esse código na p:dialog?

Comment: Não necessariamente, a ativação do evento de resize já executa todo o bloco necessário para que as ações sejam feitas, mas é uma boa prática que você coloque todo o código dentro de uma Closure sim e em seguida execute-a no carregamento da página.

Comment: Obrigada pelos esclarecimentos @Apolo Master, tenho pouco conhecimento em JavaScript